# Django-import-export, Export to xlsx only one model object. Django

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am completely new Django and I am building an e-commerce website with Django. I want to export the model's object to xlsx format. I am using django-import-export library to do that but the problem is this library exports model's all objects. I just want to export only one object. For example, if someone orders a product I want that order object export to xlsx format. I can write that in python shell but I want it to be done in the admin panel. In the picture below you can see my Order model and OrderItem model. How can I export exactly like in the picture to xlsx.

[Order model in admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjf9n.png)

Models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (("NEW", "NEW"), ("ACCEPTED", "ACCEPTED"), ("COMPLETED", "COMPLETED"))
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS,default='NEW')
    total = models.FloatField()
    adminnote = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ordered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
def __str__(self):
    return self.name + self.surname

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

admin.py

```
class OrderProductline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    readonly_fields = ('order', 'product', 'price', 'quantity', 'total_price')
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0

class OrderResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

class OrderAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'surname', 'phone', 'address', 'total', 'status', 'ordered_at']
    list_filter = ['status']
    exclude = ['customer']
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'total')
    can_delete = False
    inlines = [OrderProductline]
    resource_class = OrderResource

class OrderProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['order', 'product', 'price', 'quantity','total_price']
    list_filter = ['order']

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin,)
admin.site.register(OrderItem, OrderProductAdmin)
```

I am using Django 3.0.0 python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) running.  Then look into the source to see how objects are exported from within the example app.

`django-import-export` is best suited to exporting objects one per line, if you only need one line in your csv, then this would be possible.  Look at overriding [`before_export()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.before_export) to limit the data you are exporting.

If you need multiple objects exported (e.g. on different lines), then this might be possible, but `django-import-export` might not be the best library for that use case.

Comment: Thank you for an Idea