# Django import-export, only export one object with related objects

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a form which enables a user to register on our website. Now I need to export all the data to excel, so I turned towards the import-export package. I have 3 models, Customer, Reference and Contact. The latter two both have a m2m with Customer. I also created Resources for these models. When I use `Resource().export()` at the end of my `done()` method in my form view, it exports *all* existing objects in the database, which is not what I want.

I tried googling this and only got one [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085629/django-import-export-export-to-xlsx-only-one-model-object-django/70287788#70287788), which basically says I need to use `before_export()`, but I can't find anywhere in the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085629/django-import-export-export-to-xlsx-only-one-model-object-django/70287788#70287788) how it actually works.

I tried querying my customer manually like:

```
customer = Customer.objects.filter(pk=customer.id)

customer_data = CustomerResource().export(customer)
```

which works fine but then I'm stuck with the related references and contacts: `reference_data = ReferenceResource().export(customer.references)` gives me an TypeError saying `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`. Which makes sense because `export()` expects an queryset, but I'm not sure if it's possible getting it that way.

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Try to add this line ``ReferenceResource().export(customer.references.all())`` this will return a queryset

Comment: Yes that did the trick thanks! Now I need to figure out how to attach export().xls to an email...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to override `get_queryset()`, you could potentially try to load all related data in a single query:

```
class ReferenceResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def __init__(self, customer_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.customer_id = customer_id

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Customer.objects.filter(pk=self.customer.id)
        # additional filtering here
        return qs

    class Meta:
        model = Reference
        # add fields as appropriate
        fields = ('id', )
```

To handle m2m relationships, you may be able to modify the queryset to add these additional fields.

This isn't the complete answer but it may help you make progress.